# Proceed to localhost (unsafe) causes HTTP ERROR 403

Tags: windows, google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate

l am using `local-ssl-proxy`(a js module) to test ssl in the development environment.
When l head to `https://localhost`, it's a unsafe connection. l click "ADVANCED" and then "Proceed to localhost (unsafe)".

The browser reports an error

```
Request to access localhost was denied
You are not authorized to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

l do that once before and it worked well, can anyone give some advice?l checked all the potential problem but found nothing, l think maybe it's a browser problem?

Comment: Clear your browser and try again. Usually the unsafe warning is for a server certificate that is self signed. If you aren't using https with a self signed cert something else is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but l need test https to develop, but when l press proceed to localhost(unsafe), it reports 403

Comment: 403 is forbidden. It means whatever is serving http/https is rejecting the connection. What's serving http/https on your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Review the the request in developer tools to verify that the page isn't trying to use NTLM authentication, which may automatically attempt to use your windows login, instead of prompting you for credentials.

also, I've noticed that Chrome will ALWAYS fail to negotiate NTLM if developer tools is opened when a page requests NTLM authentication, try closing developer tools if you have it open when you visit the page.